# Link multiple files to same console window in JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there a way in JupyterLab to link different files to the same console window? Suppose I have files A.py and B.py and that I right-click the filename tab for A.py and select "New Console for Editor". Now I if do the same for B.py it will give me the option to "Use Kernel from Other Session", where I can select the kernel that is already running for A.py. However, there will still be two different console windows open, one for A.py and one for B.py, albeit linked to the same kernel. I would like there to be just a single console window that receives input from both A.py and B.py. This would be something more similar to the default behavior in PyCharm or RStudio, where you have a single console window that accepts input from many different files.